# Acegi password encryption

Tags: passwords, md5, spring-security

I am using the acegi groovy plugin for user registration and authentication.
The User domain class which comes with the plug-in has the following definition (and comments).

```
class User {
static transients = ['pass']
static hasMany = [authorities: Role]
static belongsTo = Role

/** Username */
String username
/** User Real Name*/
String userRealName
/** MD5 Password */
String passwd
/** enabled */
boolean enabled

String email
boolean emailShow

/** description */
String description = ''
...
```

}

and so on. Therefore I've assumed that the password encryption method is MD5.

I have to register many thousand of users, generating a random password for each user.
(username is already given).

I wrote a script which generates random -plain- passwords and MD5 Encrypted paswords and
make the respective inserts into the DB.
Unfortunately none of these users can log in.

Is the acegi security plug in  using MD5 encryption?

Seems to be that it is using something else.
Unfortunately I didn't find anything at the documentation.

Anybody knows how is this encryption done?

Thanks!

Luis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [`DaoAuthenticationProvider`](http://www.acegisecurity.org/acegi-security/apidocs/org/acegisecurity/providers/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html) and do not set the [`passwordEncoder`](http://www.acegisecurity.org/acegi-security/apidocs/org/acegisecurity/providers/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html#setPasswordEncoder(org.acegisecurity.providers.encoding.PasswordEncoder)) property, the default password encoder is [`PlaintextPasswordEncoder`](http://www.acegisecurity.org/acegi-security/apidocs/org/acegisecurity/providers/encoding/PlaintextPasswordEncoder.html).  To configure an MD5 password encoder, do

```
  <bean
      id="passwordEncoder"
      class="org.acegisecurity.providers.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"/>

  <bean
      id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
      class="org.acegisecurity.providers.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
  </bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1 for you. No, I didn't set anything. Now, I found at the DefaultSecurityConfig.groovy that the algorithm is 'SHA'.
Do you know how to generate SHA-encrypted passwords?

Thanks!

Comment: echo -n password | openssl sha1

Answer (score 0):

or you could use the authenticateService.encodePassword("password"). See the plugin's RegisterController's save method for example